# How reliable of using "nameofmychoice="anyname""

Tags: command-line, database

For backup MySQL MyISAM database, I'm using:

```
backupdb=siteone
mysqldump -u root -pthepass --lock-tables --add-locks --disable-keys --skip-extended-insert --quick $backupdb > /var/www/html/db2.sql
```

Even after long time using it, I still dont know what is the name of using `nameofmychoice=anyname`.

After typing `backupdb=siteone` I need to know how long it will kept in memory? If I running many lines of command which takes very long time, do I need to type `backupdb=siteone` again and again from time to time to regenerate the alias?

Is using this way really safe for almost anything? I'm worried of data loss since I'm dealing with database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example, `backupdb` is called a variable. A shell variable will be there until you change it to a new value, or the shell exits (most likely because you type `exit`, or close the terminal). In your case, `backupdb` will be there for a long time, so you don't need to type that again and again.

My guess is that you are using the BASH shell because it's quite popular. If you want to find out more you can read [the BASH programming intro](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-5.html).